# Gas required exceeds limit

Tags: ethereum, remix, metamask

I'm trying to deploy the following contract on Ropsten using an injected web3 environment (i.e. metamask) on remix.ethereum.org/

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract Coin {
    // The keyword "public" makes those variables
    // readable from outside.
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // Events allow light clients to react on
    // changes efficiently.
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    // This is the constructor whose code is
    // run only when the contract is created.
    function Coin() public {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

I've been able to create contracts with ease using remix before. I'm not sure what has changed, but I can't create contracts at all because of the gas limit thing. I've even gone as far as setting the gas limit to 2 full Ethers (i.e. value 1 ether with max of 2). I have close to 3 ethers in my metamask wallet. The remix "Account" dropdown also displays my metamask address correctly so it seems that the injected environment is connected.

When I try to create this contract I can't get past the gas required exceeds limit 2 error. I'm scratching my head as to why this simple contract would exceed the cost of 2 full Ethers.

Other parameters for remix in use:

## optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.20+commit.3155dd80.js

Is there a setting on remix that I've forgotten? I'm Trying to deploy this from Chrome.

edit: I'm still scratching my head on this one. I was able to create the contract above for a brief moment after refreshing my page, but I came in today to try and run the code from https://www.ethereum.org/token and I can't get past the exceeds gas error with a value of 20 Gwei and a limit of 3000000. Note, I tried using the simple sample contract above and I'm back to where I was when I started - even the simple "Coin" contract above apparently exceeds the gas limit.

edit 2: Well, I think I'm getting somewhere. I've changed the compiler version from "soljson-v0.4.20+commit.3155dd80.js" to "soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js". Then I refresh the page 3 times. After that I wait a couple of minutes and things seem to be working again. There is something else happening here because when I reject the transaction in metamask and then return to remix to create again, I encounter the gas exceeded error. I don't believe the issue here is metamask as I've tried to connect locally using testrpc - localhost:8545 - and experience the same issue. All I can say is that the same code that I try to create fails to submit because of the gas error most of the time but occasionally works regardless of compiler version.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue at all. I am running on Chrome as well (Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)) using MetaMask (3.14.1). Are the Gwei/limit values your using coming from the Remix UI or what you see when you approve the transaction in MetaMask?

Comment: It is in the Remix UI.